# Displaying all categories and posts on one page in a hierarchy

Tags: php, wordpress, archive, custom-taxonomy

My client insists on having all categories and posts displayed on one page. Bad idea, I know, but I need to do it.

Anyway, the structure is something like this:

1st Level Category Title > 2nd Level Category Title > ... > nth Level Category Title > Post Content.

This will be structured in HTML something like:

```
<div class="cat primary">
    <h2>1st Level Category Title</h2>
    <div class="cat secondary">
        <h3>2nd Level Category Title</h3>
        <div class="cat tertiary">
            <h4>3rd Level Category Title</h4>
            ...
                <div class="cat tertairy">
                    <h4>nth Level Category Title</h4>
                    <div class="product">
                        <p>Post Content</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cat secondary">
        <h3>2nd Level Category Title</h3>
        <div class="product">
            <p>Post Content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Explanation of functionality:

- The first category gets a class of "primary", the second "secondary", and all subsequent "tertiary". I can work around this with CSS if need be.
- `<h2>` is used for primary title, `<h3>` is used for secondary title, `<h4>` is used for all subsequent. I can work around this with CSS if need be.
- The deepest level of category in a tree displays any products in that category.

I've tried several things with `get_terms()` and `get_categories()`, but I can't figure out how to tell if a category is at its deepest level, and I can't figure out how to go infinitely deep in to a category tree (I end up having to duplicate my code for each new layer).

I'm current experimenting with this:

```
$categories = get_terms("product-category"); 
if ($categories && !is_wp_error($categories)) {
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $children = get_terms("product-category", array(
            "parent"   => $category->term_id,
        ));
        if (count($children) == 0) {
            echo $category->name;
        }
    }
}
```

This does check to see if it's the deepest in a tree, but it doesn't actually construct the tree. I'll keep toying with it and report back any progress. Help would be immensely appreciated.

---

**UPDATE 4:** With a lot of help from @Nemutaisama, I was able to figure this out! Here's my final code (slightly modified from their answer below):

```
function loadCategories($categories, $level) {
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $cat_class = "";
        $heading_tag = "";
        if ($level == 1) {
            $cat_class = "primary";
            $heading_tag = "h2 style='text-align:center;'";
        } elseif ($level == 2) {
            $cat_class = "secondary";
            $heading_tag = "h3";
        } else {
            $cat_class = "tertiary";
            $heading_tag = "h4";
        }
        echo "<section class='cat $cat_class'>";
        echo "<header>";
        echo "<$heading_tag>{$category->name}<button>Expand</button></$heading_tag>";
        if ($level == 1) {
            echo "<hr  class='short' />";
        }
        echo "</header>";
        if ($level > 1) {
            echo "<div class='expander'>";
        }
        $children = get_terms("product-category", array(
            "parent"   => $category->term_id,
        ));
        if (count($children) == 0) {
            $posts = get_posts(array(
                "post_type" => "products",
                "tax_query" => array(
                    array(
                        "field"    => "term_id",
                        "taxonomy" => "product-category",
                        "terms"    => $category->term_id,
                )),
            ));
            foreach ($posts as $post) {
                if ($level < 2) {
                    $cat_class = "secondary";
                    $heading_tag = "h3";
                } else {
                    $cat_class = "tertiary";
                    $heading_tag = "h4";
                }
                echo "<section class='cat $cat_class'>";
                echo "<header><$heading_tag>{$post->post_title}<button>Expand</button></$heading_tag></header>";
                echo "<div class='expander'>";
                echo "<article>";
                if (get_field("product_number", $post->ID)) {
                    echo "<div class='productNumber'><p># " . get_field("product_number", $post->ID) . "</p></div>";
                }
                echo "<div class='content'>";
                echo wpautop($post->post_content);
                echo "</div><!--/.content-->";
                echo "</article>";
                echo "</div><!--/.expander-->";
                echo "</section><!--/.cat.$cat_class-->";
            }
        }
        loadCategories($children, $level+1);
        if ($level > 1) {
            echo "</div><!--/.expander-->";
        }
        echo "</section><!--/.cat.$cat_class-->";
    }
}
$categories = get_terms("product-category", array(
    "parent" => 0,
));
if ($categories && !is_wp_error($categories)) {
    loadCategories($categories, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think recursive function will help you.
something like this

```
function loadCategories($categories, $level) {
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $children = get_terms("product-category", array(
            "parent"   => $category->term_id,
        ));
        $cat_class = "";
        $heading_tag = "";
        if ($level == 1) {
            $cat_class = "primary";
            $heading_tag = "h2 style='text-align:center;'";
        } elseif ($level == 2) {
            $cat_class = "secondary";
            $heading_tag = "h3";
        } else {
            $cat_class = "tertiary";
            $heading_tag = "h4";
        }
        echo "<section class='cat $cat_class'>";
        echo "<header>";
        echo "<$heading_tag>{$category->name}<button>Expand</button></$heading_tag>";
        if ($level == 1) {
            echo "<hr  class='short' />";
        }
        echo "</header>";
        if ($level > 1) {
            echo "<div class='expander'>";
        }
        if (count($children) == 0) {
            $posts = get_posts(array(
                "post_type" => "products",
                "tax_query" => array(
                    array(
                        "field"    => "term_id",
                        "taxonomy" => "product-category",
                        "terms"    => $category->term_id,
                )),
            ));
            foreach ($posts as $post) {
                if ($level < 2) {
                    $cat_class = "secondary";
                    $heading_tag = "h3";
                } else {
                    $cat_class = "tertiary";
                    $heading_tag = "h4";
                }
                echo "<section class='cat $cat_class'>";
                echo "<header><$heading_tag>{$post->post_title}<button>Expand</button></$heading_tag></header>";
                echo "<div class='expander'>";
                echo "<article>";
                if (get_field("product_number", $post->ID)) {
                    echo "<div class='productNumber'><p># " . get_field("product_number", $post->ID) . "</p></div>";
                }
                echo "<div class='content'>";
                echo wpautop($post->post_content);
                echo "</div><!--/.content-->";
                echo "</article>";
                echo "</div><!--/.expander-->";
                echo "</section><!--/.cat.$cat_class-->";
            }
        }
        loadCategories($children, $level+1);
        if ($level > 1) {
            echo "</div><!--/.expander-->";
        }
        echo "</section><!--/.cat.$cat_class-->";
    }
}
$categories = get_terms("product-category");
if ($categories && !is_wp_error($categories)) {
    loadCategories($categories, 1);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to do what I'm looking for. It appears you have to pass a level variable, and also that every post gets nested within the previous post. I need this to work kind of like combined archive pages, where everything is organized by category, but in hierarchical divs. I'll keep working on mine for now.

Comment: You will need to pass level variable only once, and only for handle `h1, h2, h3` tags.

Comment: I see, I've made some modifications (Update 2 in the original post), but I'm having some issues still. It's outputting categories both in their correct spot and in the top level list. I'm also still seeing posts duplicate with this, I assume because they're all showing up for each category rather than just their own.

Comment: Can you show html output example how it is and how it should be?

Comment: Sure, posted a paste bin in the original question. I figured out the post duplication issue (I wasn't querying by taxonomy correctly), but I'm still unable to figure out the duplicate categories thing. Take a look at the demo: http://girards.myweblinx.net/products/ In that demo, Bleu Cheese is a sub-category of Creamy Dressing, and should only show up as such, not in the main category listings.

Comment: First thing to do - move `loadCategories($children, $level+1);` before `expander` closing.

Comment: Just tried that, doesn't appear to have made any difference.

Comment: Damn. forgot. Does `$categories = get_terms("product-category");` return all categories or only top level? You need only top level categories from this function.

Comment: Aha! Passing `"parent" => 0` fixed it!